# Configuring Specflow+XUnit Tests to run on multiple environments

Tags: c#, xunit, specflow

I have to migrate my existing tests from Specflow+Runner to Specflow+xUnit and for the same I'have been stuck on converting the .runsettings and .srprofile files so that they can be used with Specflow+xUnit.

Has anyone done this conversion or can help me with this ?

## Existing .runsettings file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunSettings>
  <!-- Configurations for SpecRun -->
  <SpecRun>
      <Profile>DEV.srprofile</Profile>
    <!-- SpecRun uses VisualStudo.srprofile or TFS.srprofile by default, or the Default.srprofile if these don't exist. 
    <Profile>MyProfile.srprofile</Profile> -->
    
    <!-- SpecRun generates a report file based on the project name and the current timestamp by default.
    <ReportFile>CustomReport.html</ReportFile>-->
    
    <GenerateSpecRunTrait>false</GenerateSpecRunTrait> <!-- Set this to "true" to generate a "SpecRun" trait for all tests discovered by SpecRun (useful when the solution contains other tests too) -->
    <GenerateFeatureTrait>false</GenerateFeatureTrait> <!-- Set this to "true" to generate a feature trait for all scenarios (othervise the feature goruping can be used as "class") -->
  </SpecRun>
</RunSettings>
```

## Existing .srprofile file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TestProfile xmlns="http://www.specflow.org/schemas/plus/TestProfile/1.5">
  <Settings projectName="example" />
  <Execution stopAfterFailures="3" testThreadCount="1" testSchedulingMode="Sequential" />
  <!-- For collecting by a SpecRun server update and enable the following element. For using the 
      collected statistics, set testSchedulingMode="Adaptive" attribute on the <Execution> element.
    <Server serverUrl="http://specrunserver:6365" publishResults="true" />
  -->
  <TestAssemblyPaths>
    <TestAssemblyPath>example.dll</TestAssemblyPath>
  </TestAssemblyPaths>
  <DeploymentTransformation>
    <Steps>
        <ConfigFileTransformation configFile="App.config">
                <Transformation>
                    <![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                <configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
                <appSettings>
                <add key="baseUrl" value="<sample URL>" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" />    
                <add key="shortWait" value="15" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" />
                <add key="longWait" value="25" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes"  />
                </appSettings>
                </configuration>
                        ]]>
                </Transformation>
            </ConfigFileTransformation>
    </Steps>
  </DeploymentTransformation>
</TestProfile>
```